# Consumers disconnect from Broker

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a spring boot application acting as a consumer. Our Spring Boot application is running on the AWS Beanstalk application.

We have Kafka brokers running on a different K8 cluster.

We have configured all the available brokers in our application.

Now the problem is that whenever we change the number of instances manually or whenever the load balancer changes the instances based upon the traffic, the application's connection to the brokers is severed and it stops consuming the messages. All our consumers go silent and the consumer lag keeps increasing. We have to manually re-deploy the application again.

I am not sure what could be going wrong here. I am sharing the configuration for our consumer:

```
# Impression F-Cap Kafka Configs
impression.fcap.kafka.producer.configurations.bootstrap.servers=${KAFKA_BROKERS:http://localhost:9092}
impression.fcap.kafka.producer.configurations.client.id=${IMPRESSION_FCAP_KAFKA_PRODUCER_CLIENT_ID:ad-tech-impression-freq-cap-processor}
impression.fcap.kafka.producer.configurations.acks=all
impression.fcap.kafka.producer.configurations.key.serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
impression.fcap.kafka.consumer.configurations.bootstrap.servers=${GM_KAFKA_BROKERS:http://localhost:9092}
impression.fcap.kafka.consumer.configurations.client.id=${IMPRESSION_FCAP_KAFKA_CONSUMER_CLIENT_ID:ad-tech-impression-freq-cap-processor}
impression.fcap.kafka.consumer.configurations.group.id=${IMPRESSION_FCAP_CONSUMER_GROUP:impression-freq-cap-consumer}
impression.fcap.kafka.consumer.configurations.max.poll.records=500
impression.fcap.kafka.consumer.configurations.max.poll.interval.ms=2147483647
impression.fcap.kafka.consumer.configurations.key.deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
impression.fcap.kafka.consumer.dlqConfigurations.bootstrap.servers=${KAFKA_BROKERS:http://localhost:9092}
impression.fcap.kafka.consumer.dlqConfigurations.client.id=${IMPRESSION_FCAP_KAFKA_DLQ_CONSUMER_CLIENT_ID:ad-tech-impression-freq-cap-dlq-processor}
impression.fcap.kafka.consumer.dlqConfigurations.group.id=${IMPRESSION_FCAP_KAFKA_DLQ_CONSUMER_GROUP:impression-freq-cap-dlq-consumer}
impression.fcap.kafka.consumer.dlqConfigurations.auto.offset.reset=earliest

# Kafka Client Common Configs
kafka.client.common.topics.click-banner-enriched=${CLICK_BANNER_ENRICHED:adtech.event.click.banner.enriched}
kafka.client.common.topics.click-banner-enriched-dlq=${CLICK_BANNER_ENRICHED_DLQ:adtech.event.click.banner.enriched.ad-tech-click-freq-cap-processor.dlq}
kafka.client.common.topics.widget-serve-audit-log=${WIDGET_SERVE_AUDIT_LOG:trigger.external.widget.audit.serve}
kafka.client.common.topics.widget-serve-audit-log-dlq=${WIDGET_SERVE_AUDIT_LOG_DLQ:trigger.external.widget.audit.serve.ad-tech-impression-freq-cap-processor.dlq}
kafka.producer.retry.max.attempts=${KAFKA_PRODUCER_RETRY_MAX_ATTEMPTS:5}
kafka.producer.retry.first.backoff.millis=${KAFKA_PRODUCER_RETRY_FIRST_BACKOFF_MILLIS:5000}
kafka.producer.retry.max.backoff.millis=${KAFKA_PRODUCER_RETRY_MAX_BACKOFF_MILLIS:30000}
```

Comment: How long consumers are in silent? Forever? If it changes a number of consumers in same the same consumer group, rebalancing occurs. In the middle of rebalancing, consumers cannot consume any messages. Another question,.. where is the load balancer? Consumers or brokers?

Comment: @J.Song Consumers are silent forever until we re-deploy the application. When I say load balancers, I am talking about the consumer application load balance, so, the lb is at consumer end.